# Unable to classify components

Tags: 2011, cme

I just completed installing and configuring Tridion Content Manager 2011 SP2. I am unable to classify any component using keywords.

I have created categories and keywords in my publication and I am trying to classify a component using the same. But none of the categories are appearing the window which opens up on selecting "Classify" option of the component.

Any pointers on what I might be missing here?

Comment: Looks like you have an answer already, but maybe just for CMS admins. Per the [documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/task_29_2DDAFF2CF95E4430AA0F27AD7A91B5F8) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) you'll need item rights, write permission on the containing folder, and (easily overlooked) *read* to the Category.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The schema on which your component is based on should have at least one Keyword field (a Text field with values coming from Category).  Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: @user755: in that case please accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of it. That will help others find this answer.